# Python-Killing one python process by its script name from more python process

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my windows server two or three python process are running.
For ex:

```
C:\Users\nithya>wmic processess where caption="python.exe" get commandline
CommandLine

python  -i -Wignore sample_test.py
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\examples\testing.py" --q
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\examples\gui.py"  --i
```

From the above processess I want to kill sample_test.py from testing.py or from gui.py using python code.

Is there any safe way to kill only that python process without killing all python process?

Which method is best to do that ? may be psutil or os or subprocess?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should specify the relation between the processes, i.e. parent-chiled process relationships. A parent process can easily terminate a child process if it was spawned through the subprocess module.

Comment: There is no relationship between them.Its a separate process